# Creating a list within an object (book/patron waitlist)

Tags: python, list, methods, instantiation

I have a homework assignment to create a "library" with a patron class and book class. This library should allow people to check out up to 3 books, and add a book to a patron's waitlist if the book is already checked out. Upon the books return, it should be automatically checked out to the first person on the waitlist. I can't seem to get the list to work. Here's my code:

```
class Patron(object):
def __init__(self,name,booksOut=0):
    self._name=name
    self._booksOut=booksOut

def getBooksOut(self):
    return self._booksOut

def __str__(self):
    result="Name: "+self._name+"\n"
    result+="Books Out: "+str(self._booksOut)+"\n"
    return result


class Book(object):
def __init__(self,title,author,owner=None):
    self._title=title
    self._author=author
    self._owner=owner
    self._queue=[] #Here is the empty list I'm using... but it doesn't seem to be working.

def setOwner(self,owner):
    self._owner=owner

def getOwner(self):
    return self._owner

def borrowMe(self, patron):
    if self._owner != None:
        return "This book is not available. You've been added to the queue.\n"
        self._queue.append(patron)
        print(str(self._queue)) #I can't even get the list to print, so I'm feeling like I didn't create it correctly
    else:
        if patron.getBooksOut()>=3:
            return "You have too many books checked out!"
        else:
            self.setOwner(patron)
            patron._booksOut+=1
            return "You have successfully checked this book out."

def returnMe(self):
    if len(self._queue)==0:
        self.setOwner(None)
        return "Your book has been returned."
    else:
        return "Your book has been given to: "+str(self._queue[0])
        self.borrowMe(self._queue[0]) #Here is where I'm trying to automatically borrow the book to the first person in the waitlist

def __str__(self):
    result="Title: "+self._title+"\n"
    result+="Author: "+self._author+"\n"
    if self._owner != None:
        result+="Owner: "+str(self.getOwner())
    else:
        result+="Owner: None"
    return result


def main():
"""Tests the Patron and Book classes."""
p1 = Patron("Ken")
p2 = Patron("Martin")
b1 = Book("Atonement", "McEwan")
b2 = Book("The March", "Doctorow")
b3 = Book("Beach Music", "Conroy")
b4 = Book("Thirteen Moons", "Frazier")
print(b1.borrowMe(p1))
print(b2.borrowMe(p1))
print(b3.borrowMe(p1))
print(b1.borrowMe(p2))
print(b4.borrowMe(p1))
print(p1)
print(b1)
print(b4)
print(b1.returnMe())
print(b2.returnMe())
print(b1)
print(b2)
```

I've #commented the parts containing the list creation (in the **init** for the book class) and where I tried to print the list to do some error checking (in the borrowMe method) and also where I am trying to automatically borrow the book to the first person on the waitlist/queue (in the returnMe method).

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
if self._owner != None:
        return "This book is not available. You've been added to the queue.\n"
        self._queue.append(patron)
        print(str(self._queue))
```

You are printing after `return`. Nothing will be executed after `return`. Change it to `print`. Also in `Patron` class, change `__str__` to `__repr__`. Otherwise it will print a list of memory addresses. In addition, `print(str(self._queue))` is redundant, you could print the list directly.